# Browser doesn't reload with gulp and livereload

Tags: node.js, gulp, pug

Please forgive me if this may seem like a duplicate question, but I have read every resource I could find to help me determine the root of my problem.

I am trying to have gulp reload Chrome after I have compiled a jade file.  I have this for my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    jade       = require('gulp-jade'),
    connect    = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('jade', function() {
   return gulp.src('src/*.jade')
      .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/'))
      .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('connect', function() {
   connect.server({
      livereload: true,
      root: 'dev',
      debug: true
   });
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch('src/*.jade', ['jade']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch']);
```

My filestructure is:

```
.
├── dev/
│   └── index.html
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   └── index.jade
├── gulpfile.js
└── package.json
```

Upon typing `gulp` in the command line, everything appears to be fine; my jade files are compiled whenever saved, however Chrome is not refreshed.  A few remarks:

- I have the LiveReload extension installed on chrome, and the extension icon says "LiveReload is connected" when I am on http://localhost:8080
- I have eneabled "Allow Access to File URLS" in the Chrome extensions preferences for the LiveReload extension.
- When gulp is running, http://localhost:35729  returns then json `{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.2.1"}`.
- I've tried this both on Windows and Linux without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try using other tool  «Live Reload Browser Page» https://github.com/Yuriy-Svetlov/live-reload-bp    Or website:  https://live-reload-browser-page.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Livereload seems to not work reliably in newer versions of `gulp-connect`, see [Livereload is broken since 3.0.0](https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/165).

I tried your Gulpfile using `gulp-connect@3.1.1` and I couldn't get livereload to work either. However falling back to version `2.3.1` of `gulp-connect` as suggested in the linked issue thread did fix the problem. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Indeed `npm install --save-dev gulp-connect@2.3.1` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the browser didn't refresh because I had **another instance of phpStorm** already running with livereload. So, be sure you are only running it once.